# How to check some of the checkbox inside multiple checkbox list using Selenium in c#

Tags: c#, selenium, checkbox, automation, selenium-chromedriver

I am working on Automation Project, there are multiple checkboxes and they don't have any ID.

CheckBox look like,

[image]

and i want to check **Level 3 A** and **Level 1 B** checkBox.

Added DOM pictures:

[image]

[image]

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you give us the complete HTML DOM please?

Comment: show us your code and DOM.

Answer (score 0):

**Overall idea:**

For handling situations like this we need to use the advanced xpathing methods. In general we are having 13 xpath axes, which we can use to navigate in the DOM effectively keeping some element as the reference. Refer here for more details regarding the various xpath axes.

https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_axes.asp

In this case, i am keeping the element with text Levle 3 A as reference and moving to its checkbox. We can update the name the checkbox alone to click that particular box.

```
"//span[contains(text(),'Levle 3 A')]/parent::span/input"
```

Hope this helps. Thanks.